# C# bind Object to a JSON file?

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, deserialization, two-way-binding

### I have an Object:

```
public class BindObjectToFile
{
    public int Property1 {get; set;}
    public int Property2 {get; set;}

    public BindObjectToFile(string BindingFilePath)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

### I have a Json File:

```
{
    "Property1" : 1,
    "Property2" : 2,
}
```

- Whenever a property on the **Object** Changes, I want the **Json File** to change with it.
- Whenever a property in the **JsonFile** Changes, I want the **Object** to change with it.
- I'd like all children of BindObjectToFile to easily inherit this functionality, without requiring adjustments to the getters/setters on their properties.

***Essentially*, *I want an object that feels like it is stored in a file, not in memory.***

## What I've Tried:

1. I started by (stupidly) Serializing/Deserializing the entire object on every single getter/setter in the object:

```
     internal int _property1;
     public int Property1
     {
         get
         {
             return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObjectToFile>(File.ReadAllText(JsonFilePath))._property1;
         }
         set
         {
             _property1 = value;
             File.WriteAllText(JsonFilePath, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this));
         }
     }
```

Newtonsoft.json is great, But this approach seems wrong because it forces me to rewrite all of that boiler plate for each property on each new child without communicating to anyone that that is how my BindObjectToFile class is supposed to be used.

2. Next, I tried implementing`INotifyPropertyChanged` to only save the newly serialized object when a property changes. This was a little better, but it still doesn't account for situations where the file is changed by something other than this instance of 'BindObjectToFile'.
3. I tried Creating a Generic BindObjectToFile which also implemented INotifyPropertyChanged. I did this in hopes that by using a Generic object, I could get around this problem without using inheritance, so that I wouldn't need to find a way to force children to write crazy getters/setters for each of their properties:

```
    public abstract class ObjectToFile<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public T _value;
        public T Value
        {
            get
            { 
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(File.ReadAllText(Path));
            }
            set 
            {
                _value = value;
                File.WriteAllText(Path, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_value ));
            }
        }
        public string JsonFilePath;

        public ObjectToFile(T value, string path)
        {
            _value = value;
            JsonFilePath = path;
        }
   }
```

But, this still forces me to either raise or manage PropertyChange events in the child classes when their properties change.

And I don't want to do any of that--I Just want a fix-the-problem parent class so that I can happily create child classes that behave correctly without me needing to think about any of this.

That seems reasonable, right?

## Caveats:

- I don't mind rewriting/rereading the entire file every time a property is accessed or changed.
- In my context, I don't care much about speed. If someone else opens up one of these files and I have to wait a few hundred ms for my turn, that's not a problem.
- All the objects that I'm working with are extremely simple, containing properties with basic data types.
- All the objects that I'm working with are extremely small, and rarely have more than five or six properties.

Thanks, All!

Comment: Is the file subject to changes from more than one consumer?

Comment: Yes, the file is heavily subject to outside change--that's a big part of the reason the state is going into the file in the first place.

Comment: The only way to solve this issue is to create your own FileContext (give it a good name) with a change tracker that works two ways, from the objects and the file system. But you have to thing of a way to lock the file when you are working on it, so no one else can apply changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can only change part of a json file, to only save the property value that was changed. If the length of value changed, it would have to move the rest of the file up or down and I don't think you can do that. So you will have to rewrite the entire file every time. Which really sucks if some code changes more than one property at a time. I would probably add a `.Save` method or maybe even add change tracking with a `.Commit` when done making changes - so the file is written once per set of changes. This also helps to communicate to anyone using the class that that is how the object is to be used.

You also shouldn't be reading/deserializing the file every time a property is referenced. I would instead try using the [FileSystemWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher) class (setting the `Filter` property) to be notified of changes to the file.

If the number of consumers watching the same file is an issue, perhaps look into using a document/nosql database instead of manually doing it yourself.

Comment: Thanks, Jeff. After playing with it, I think that [FileSystemWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=netframework-4.8) might be a viable option. If I have many of these FileToMemory Objects, would you recomend having them share a single FileSystemWatcher, or would it be better to spin off a new one for each new instance?
I'll post the final version and throw you an upvote once i get it all hashed out.

Comment: I would probably try a single watcher per folder with a `Dictionary<string, FileToMemory>` where the key would be the filename or full path, whatever is passed to the event handler. Would make it super easy to reference the appropriate object.